# How to use golang create nest json array object

Tags: go, go-gin

I try to query database and use query result to create json like these

[ {"TransID": "Transaction ID1",ProductID": ["ProID1","ProID2","ProID3","ProID4" ]},

{"TransID": "Transaction ID2","ProductID": ["ProID5","ProID6" ]} ]

so I create type struct from

```
type DataRecent []struct {
 TransID   string   `json:"transID"`
 ProductID []string `json:"productID"`}
```

and golang code is

```
var dataRecent DataRecent
var recent [5]string
for _, Trans := range recent {

    if Trans != "" {
        var TransID, ProductID string

        selectTrans, err := db.Query("select transaction_id, product_id from detail where transaction_id = ?", Trans)

        var arr []string
        for selectTrans.Next() {
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            errTrans := selectTrans.Scan(&TransID, &ProductID)
            if errTrans != nil {
                panic(errTrans.Error())
            }
            arr = append(arr, ProductID)
        }
    }
        dataRecent.TransID = Trans
        dataRecent.ProductID = arr

}
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "success", "message": "Find transactions success", "recent_trans": dataRecent})


defer db.Close()
```

but I can't build the code and got error

> dataRecent.TransID undefined (type DataRecent has no field or method TransID)
>   dataRecent.ProductID undefined (type DataRecent has no field or method ProductID)

I don't know what to do and stuck with these for a week. I am new programmer for golang. Help me pleae, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the array when you create the struct

```
type DataRecent struct {
 TransID   string   `json:"transID"`
 ProductID []string `json:"productID"`
}
```

and do

```
var dataRecent []DataRecent
```

it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

looks like dataRecent isn't initialized. I suggest you use `dataRecent := DataRecent{}` instead of `var dataRecent DataRecent`.

some other insights: 
I'm not sure if you've omitted the usage of `make` of the recent string array, or you're not aware you need to `make()` it. Anyway, arrays are values in Go, and if you're new to Go I strongly suggest you use slices instead. https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Also, I'm not sure why you have to `panic()` in case you've found an error (in the words of Dave Cheney, `panic` means "game over man" - https://dave.cheney.net/tag/panic)